# How to handle single or multiple files from request using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, multer

My first time to handle multiple files in Node.js and Multer library. I have multiple path with file. For example employee information, product, etc. Some paths have a single field for input file but some paths have more than two fields to input file.

The conditionals:

```
       1. I should handle the files into the best suitable directory,

       2. Rename each file to unique name in the directory.

       3. Return each new name to the main function to record into database and reusable.
```

This is what I have tried. And I also attached a link to git project including example of request image.

git project:
https://github.com/Kicks-Me/multer-file-handle.git

```
import * as multer from 'multer';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import fs from 'fs';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename);

const mimeTypes = {
"image/png":"png",
"image/jpeg":"jpg",
"image/jpg":"jpg",
"image/gif":"gif",
"video/mp4":"mp4",
"audio/mpeg":"mp3",
"audio/wav":"wav",
"application/pdf":"pdf",
"application/vnd.ms-excel":"xls",
"application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet":"xlsx"
};

const accessFilePath = (fileType, reqpath) => {
   let dest = "";
   let pathType = "uploads/Others";

   if(reqpath === "/location")
   {
      pathType = "uploads/locations";
   }
   else if(reqpath === "/employee")
   {
       pathType = "uploads/employees";
   }
   else if(reqpath === "/product")
   {
      pathType = "uploads/products";
   }


   dest =
     mimeTypes[fileType] === "mp4"
     ? path.join(__dirname, "..", pathType, "video")
     : mimeTypes[fileType] === "pdf"
     ? path.join(__dirname, "..", pathType, "documents", "pdf")
     : mimeTypes[fileType] === "xls" || mimeTypes[fileType] === "xlsx"
     ? path.join(__dirname, "..", pathType, "documents", "excel")
     : mimeTypes[fileType] === "mp3" || mimeTypes[fileType] === "wav"
     ? path.join(__dirname, "..", pathType, "audio")
     : mimeTypes[fileType] === "gif"
     ? path.join(__dirname, "..", pathType, "gif")
     : path.join(__dirname, "..", pathType, "image");

  return dest;
  };

  const multerConfig = {
   storage: multer.diskStorage({
     destination: (req, file, callback) => {

  let dest = "";
  const fileType = file.mimetype;

  dest = accessFilePath(fileType, req?.path);

  if (!fs.existsSync(dest)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(dest, { recursive: true });
  }

  callback(null, dest);
},

filename: (req, file, callback) => {
  const ext = mimeTypes[file.mimetype];
  callback(null, `${uuidv4()}.${ext}`);
},
}),

fileFilter: (req, file, callback) => {
const ext = mimeTypes[file.mimetype];

ext === "png" ||
ext === "jpg" ||
ext === "gif" ||
ext === "wav" ||
ext === "mp3" ||
ext === "wav" ||
ext === "mp4" ||
ext === "pdf" ||
ext === "xls" ||
ext === "xlsx"
  ? callback(null, true)
  : callback(null, false);
},
};

export const upload = multer.default(multerConfig);

 // Middleware to handle multiple files with different keys
export const handleMultipleFiles = (req, res, next) => {
const newImages = {};

 // Process files attached to 'Profile' key
if (req.file) {
   newImages.profile = req.file.filename;
 }

 // Process files attached to 'qr' key
 if (req.files && req.files.length > 0) {
   newImages.qr = req.files.map((file) => file.filename);
 }

  req.newImages = newImages;
 next();
};
```

Here is the route

```
import Route from 'express';
import { verifyJWT } from '../helper/jwt.js';
import { handleMultipleFiles, upload } from '../helper/multer.js';
const route = Route();

route.post('/upload',verifyJWT, upload.single('Profile'), upload.array('Images', 5), 
  handleMultipleFiles, (req, res) => {
    const profileImage = req.newImages.profile;
    const qrImages = req.newImages.qr;

    return res.json({ profileImage, qrImages });
  });

export default route;
```

From above code, I faced with some error:

```
 MulterError: Unexpected field
     at wrappedFileFilter (/Users/tplussmacbookpro2/Desktop/kkkk/file- 
 handle/node_modules/multer/index.js:40:19)
     at Multipart.<anonymous> (/Users/tplussmacbookpro2/Desktop/kkkk/file- 
 handle/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:107:7)
     at Multipart.emit (node:events:514:28)
     at HeaderParser.cb (/Users/tplussmacbookpro2/Desktop/kkkk/file- 
 handle/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:358:14)
```

You can review the attached project in github for more detail.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is an issue in the order you are calling the MW for multiple requests. I would suggest creating a MW that decides to call a single upload or multiple uploads. You can check this for reference: [link](https://www.ultimateakash.com/blog-details/Ii0zMGAKYAo=/How-to-Upload-Single-Or-Multiple-Files-in-Node.js-Express)

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara, thank you very much. The link is useful but it seem the requests are separated from each other. In my case sometimes one request contains two fields for file. As I mentioned above, one request to save employee's data. Means, the payload has field "Profile" for profile image and field "Images" for his/her gallery.

Comment: Yes, I understand and you can build your business logic around it. In the MW, you can define your schema and based on it you can easily make the decision. IMO you can keep the profile in the Images array as the first image and process it with any tag lets say isProfilePicAdded: true and do your work. This way you won't need to handle multiple areas for upload files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading multiple files with fieldnames that can be optional can be handled with [.fields()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#fieldsfields) method.

So, setup fieldnames for processing:

```
upload.fields([
  {
    name: 'Profile'
    maxCount: 1,
  },
  {
    name: 'Images',
    maxCount: 5,
  },
])
```

and then, `req.files` will contain object with corresponding fieldnames (if provided, if not, the property won't be present), for example, if both fieldnames are present:

```
//  req.files
{
    Images: [file1, file2..],
    Profile: [file]
}
```

so in the files handler, you simply check the presence of those fieldnames, and assign filenames accordingly:

```
// Process files attached to 'Profile' key
  if(req.files.Profile) {

    newImages.profile = req.files.Profile[0].filename;
  }

 // Process files attached to 'qr' key
  if(req.files.Images) {
    newImages.qr = req.files.Images.map((file) => file.filename);
  }
```

full modified code:

route:

```
   route.post('/upload',verifyJWT, upload.fields([
      {
        name: 'Profile'
        maxCount: 1,
      },
      {
        name: 'Images',
        maxCount: 5,
      },
    ]), handleMultipleFiles, (req, res) => {
    
        const profileImage = req.newImages.profile;
        const qrImages = req.newImages.qr;
    
        return res.json({ profileImage, qrImages });
      });
```

handler:

```
 // Middleware to handle multiple files with different keys
export const handleMultipleFiles = (req, res, next) => {
const newImages = {};

 // Process files attached to 'Profile' key
  if(req.files.Profile) {

    newImages.profile = req.files.Profile[0].filename;
  }

 // Process files attached to 'qr' key
  if(req.files.Images) {
    newImages.qr = req.files.Images.map((file) => file.filename);
  }

  req.newImages = newImages;
 next();
};
```

Comment: The problem is gone. I think, I get the right way but I didn't walk until the end. Thank very much. Upvote already.